# Как обновлять информацию в Qstackedwidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ребят такой вопрос у меня есть главное окно на котором размещена кнопка добавить продукт и кнопка главная, когда я жму на добавить продукт у меня открывается стек из виджетов в котором я заполняю поля, когда я жму главную кнопку, я возвращаюсь на главную страницу и если я потом жму опять добавить продукт, он открывает тот виджет на котором я остановился и все поля заполненные!

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я нажимал на главную кнопку я возвращался на главную и потом если захочу добавить еще один продукт, он обновлял виджеты в которых я заполняю информацию о продукте и открывал первый виджет и чтобы поля были пустые

Например, когда я нажимаю добавить продукт, я заполняю вот эти формы по порядку, переключая кнопкой далее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом я жму кнопку главная у меня открывается главная страничке и если снова хочу добавить новый продукт и нажимаю добавить продукт он мне открывает сразу вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне надо, чтобы открывал первый виджет и никакой старой информации в полях для заполнения не было, подскажите как это можно сделать.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton,QStackedLayout
import sys


class FormA(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnPress = QPushButton("Table AAAA")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")


class FormB(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnPress = QPushButton("Table BBBB")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")

class TextEditDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример QStackedLayout")
        self.resize(300, 270)
                 # Создать составной макет

        self.btnPress1 = QPushButton("FormA")
        self.btnPress2 = QPushButton("FormB")

        self.form1 = FormA()
        self.form2 = FormB()


        widget = QWidget()
        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        widget.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)
        widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:grey;")
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form2)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress2)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.btnPress1.clicked.connect(self.btnPress1_Clicked)
        self.btnPress2.clicked.connect(self.btnPress2_Clicked)


    def btnPress1_Clicked(self):
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def btnPress2_Clicked(self):
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TextEditDemo()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас три варианта - а) ручками обнулять все поля, б) удалять старый и создавать новые виджет заново каждый раз, когда он открывается, в) при активации вкладки пробежаться по всем деткам и обнулить их.
см. btnPress2_Clicked

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton,QStackedLayout,QLineEdit
import sys


class FormA(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnPress = QPushButton("Table AAAA")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")


class FormB(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnPress = QPushButton("Table BBBB")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.text = QTextEdit()
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")

class TextEditDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример QStackedLayout")
        self.resize(300, 270)
                 # Создать составной макет

        self.btnPress1 = QPushButton("FormA")
        self.btnPress2 = QPushButton("FormB")

        self.form1 = FormA()
        self.form2 = FormB()


        widget = QWidget()
        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        widget.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)
        widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:grey;")
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form2)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPress2)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.btnPress1.clicked.connect(self.btnPress1_Clicked)
        self.btnPress2.clicked.connect(self.btnPress2_Clicked)


    def btnPress1_Clicked(self):
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def btnPress2_Clicked(self):
        my_variant = 'c' # Какой вариант больше нравится
        if my_variant == 'a':
            self.form2.line.clear()
            self.form2.text.clear()
        if my_variant == 'b':
            self.stacked_layout.removeWidget(self.form2)
            self.form2.deleteLater()
            self.form2 = FormB()
            self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form2)
        if my_variant == 'c':
            for child in self.form2.children():
                if child.metaObject().className() in ('QLineEdit','QTextEdit'):
                    child.clear()
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TextEditDemo()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```